# PHP Kerberos delegate to SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, apache, kerberos

Is there a way to delegate session from Kerberos authentication on Apache + PHP to a SQL server connection? We want to accomplish user based connection to SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the PHP MSSQL and ODBC extensions do not provide kerberos authentication.

What could work is running PHP in IIS and using the PHP COM extension to use ADODB.Connection and follow the steps explained here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319723